# counting occurrences of certain inputs in data table/database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently populating a data table on my website from information stored in a mysql database

The table is of the form:

```
Table 1                                     

 ID | DataA | Other Info | Count Data                
 ======================================     
  1 |   A   | Other Info |      2          
  2 |   B   | Other Info |      3                     

Table 2        

ID | Input 
==========
 1 |   A
 2 |   A
 3 |   B
 4 |   B
 5 |   B
```

`Count data in table 1` is intended to show how often the `entry form the DataA` column appears in the `input column in Table2`

Update....

```
CREATE TABLE driver   (
  `ID` INTEGER,
  `DataA` VARCHAR(1),
  `Other Info` VARCHAR(10),
   primary key (ID)
);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `driver` ORDER BY drivercompany";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<tr>
    <td class='class'>" . $result['id'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $result['DataA'] . "</td>                
        <td>" . $result['otherinfo'] . "</td>
        <td></td> /**count goes here**/
        </tr>";
    }
} 
?>
```

using db fiddle, the query I need to get the count is:

```
SELECT driver.*, COUNT(add_job.Input) AS counter
FROM driver
LEFT JOIN add_job ON add_job.Input = driver.DataA
GROUP BY driver.ID
```

I have tried adding it to my code as so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `driver` ORDER BY drivercompany";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$count = "SELECT `driver`.*, COUNT(`add_job`.`adddriver`) AS counter 
        FROM `driver` 
        LEFT JOIN `add_job` ON `add_job`.`adddriver` = `driver`.`drivercompany` 
        GROUP BY `driver`.`id`";
$counter = mysqli_query($conn, $count);

while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query,$counter)) { //and other variations
```

I cannot determine how to get $count and $query to work together

Comment: @u_mulder I had a look at the question that you have marked mine to be a duplicate of and am unsure as to why? I am not looking to use mysql and mysqli together. I am aware that they should not be mixed and am not looking to mix them...

Comment: And what should `COUNT(DataA)` count?

Comment: i don't understand which results you are looking for ...See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) how to provide this..  Also you can better place the right table example under the first then we can select the tables more easy in two times to generate SQL statements..

Comment: @u_mulder I am trying to show in table 1, how many times A and B occur in table 2. It appears that `mysqli_query()` cannot be used more than once. and also that I am having issues with `mysqli_fetc_assoc()` working

Comment: @RaymondNijland already mentioned that we need `mysql` table structure instead of html-markup.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` can be used millions of times. And you still don't give us [mcve].

Comment: ....   *"already mentioned that we need mysql table structure instead of html-markup."* Which comment it seams you had deleted..  @u_mulder

Comment: @u_mulder the tables/databases are already created in mysql. I did not create them using PHP. I created them via phpmyadmin and am using php to populate them and pull data from them so there has been no `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` used

Comment: " I am trying to show in table 1, how many times A and B occur in table 2"  Not sure hat you need but take a look into these [queries](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5HFqAFip9s6cmKDn5TSaET/1)

Comment: @RaymondNijland so based on your fiddle, I had missed and `INNER JOIN` statement? so my code should read `$count = SELECT table_1.DataA, COUNT(input) FROM table1 INNER JOIN table_2 on table_1.DataA = table_2.Input GROUP BY table_1.DataA;
$counter = mysqli_query($conn, $count);`?

Comment: MIne queries where just a example based on your comment Paulmcf1987 ...  @PaulSpiegel 's answer seams to give the infromation required by the html output in the PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can JOIN the two tables, group by the primary key of `table1` and count the number of occurances in `table2` with a single query.

Assuming `ID` is the primary key in `table1`, change your query to:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT t1.*, COUNT(t2.Input) AS counter
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.Input = t1.DataA
    GROUP BY t1.ID
";
```

The result would be:

```
| ID  | DataA | Other Info | Count Data | counter |
| --- | ----- | ---------- | ---------- | ------- |
| 1   | A     | Other Info | 2          | 2       |
| 2   | B     | Other Info | 3          | 3       |
```

See the result in [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jgTmTY3Fwy1aWwSChNwkwE/0)

Then you can use `$result['counter']` in your output. Eg.:

```
echo "
    <tr>
        <td class='class'>{$result['id']}</td>
        <td>{$result['DataA']}</td>                
        <td>{$result['otherinfo']}</td>
        <td>{$result['counter']}</td>
    </tr>
";
```

**Note:** If you have the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode enabled in MySQL < 5.7 or any version of MariaDB, the query will raise an error. In this case you should change it to

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.DataA, t1.otherinfo, COUNT(t2.Input) AS counter
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.Input = t1.DataA
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.DataA, t1.otherinfo
```

To include all selected non-aggreagted columns in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @RaymondNijland What exactly would be the problem with this query, when `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` isn't enabled?

Comment: Annyhow removing mine comments.. Don't want you to have downvotes based on mine criticism about functional dependency trustworthiness because i didn't explained it fully in mine first comment..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I forgot that this is still an issue in MariaDB with default settings. But I'm kind of tired writing a "disclaimer" every time for this kind of queries. They should at least fix the performance problems, when non-index columns are included in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I clarify. If for example, table1 was called cars and table 2 was called trucks could In the code table1 and table2 would change to the names I have stated... what about the t1 and t2? would they remain the same? and t1 and t2, the reason I ask is that I cannot see t1 or t2 mentioned in the schema side of the fiddle... Also, do I add this to my php code as `$count= "SELECT..."`? or should I add ths to the code of that particular column in the mysql datable table?

Comment: Yes you can change the table names in the query. `t1` and `t2` are table aliases. You can keep them as they are. But for `cars` and `trucks` it would be more convenient to use `c` (for cars) and `t` (for trucks) instead. See changed [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mrk9QGC6dEt2Gp37HeUqRq/0)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel @RaymondNijland One last question, then hopefully im sorted lol... I went to my MYSQL database and in the table created a colum names counter... I then, inside `structure went to the counter heading > clicked More > and chose Distinct Value` I then inserted the query in there. When I looked at the table, I then had 2 columns named counter `one containing 0` the `other containing the count that I was looking for`...

Comment: In my datatable when I like the cell using `<td>".$result['counter']."</td> `it gives me `0` rather than the column with the values. how do I get the figures to appear in the correct column?
I tried renaming the initial column to count whilst linking to <td>".$result['counter']."</td> but then that column in my datatable came back blank, as though the counter column in the database doesnt actually exist?

Comment: If I remove the query from MYSQL and add it in with my current code, it does nothing... I tried: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM `driver` ORDER BY drivercompany";
      $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $count = "SELECT `driver`.*, COUNT(`add_job`.`adddriver`) AS counter 
FROM `driver` 
LEFT JOIN `add_job` ON `add_job`.`adddriver` = `driver`.`drivercompany` 
GROUP BY `driver`.`id`";
      $counter = mysqli_query($conn, $count);`                  and used `<td>".$result['counter']."</td>`

Comment: @Paulmcf1987 It's hard to understand your comments and read any code in them. If you want follow-up help, concider to create a full working fiddle. You can start [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jgTmTY3Fwy1aWwSChNwkwE/0), modify schema and data. Klick on "Fork" and repost the link.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wrWFdhjvCYZiALS4tqhyNo/6 - working fiddle... I am unsure where to put the query part in order to have the table working as it should, I am updating my question

Comment: @Paulmcf1987 So it works? Or where is the problem? Is it that you use `mysqli_query($conn, $count)` instead of `mysqli_query($conn, $sql)`?

Comment: It works, yes the problem is at the end of my updated question im struggling to figure out how to include $query and $counter together

Comment: You only need the second query! Just append `ORDER BY driver.drivercompany`.